# Converting number to binary, can't fix 0/0 error

Tags: java, divide-by-zero

Hello I have a program that successfully converts decimal to binary. However, at the end the code divides 0 by 0 resulting in an error message at the end. Here's the code.

```
import java.lang.*; 
import java.util.*;     
public class BinaryConverter {
public static void main (String[] argv) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    int number = 0;
    int factorOfTwo = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the number to convert (0-255): ");
        number = input.nextInt();
    }  while (number< 0 || number > 255);

    System.out.println("The number " + number + " converted to binary is : ");

    for (factorOfTwo = 1; factorOfTwo <= 128; factorOfTwo*=2) {
        if (number / factorOfTwo >= 1){
            System.out.print("1");
            number -= factorOfTwo;
        }
        else System.out.print ("0");
    }

} // end of main
}// end of class
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an error... your code would be cleaner if you declared variables in as small a scope as possible, but it's not giving me an error... what value is failing?

Comment: The only division is by `factorOfTwo`, and I don't see how `factorOfTwo` can be zero.

Comment: You could just use the [`toBinaryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) instead.

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but you should start with dividing by 128.

Comment: Sorry everyone, here is the error message, note that this is in Eclipse:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at Test2.main(Test2.java:28)

So obviously it is an arthmetic error, but yes the program does stop at 8 digits, so it does work, and nobody would see that error code in reality I guess. Sorry for the confusion... and i didint expect this many responses so fast.

Comment: There's a long way from _doesn't crash_ to _working_. You have to at least iterate the division (or subtraction suggested by alestanis) from highest bit to lowest. Or change the x/y>=1 operation to x%y>0 operation. (and even in that way you would be processing the bits right to left, which isn't the typical representation of binary numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no division by zero in the posted code. There is only one division and `factorOfTwo` can never be 0 in that loop.

If you still get division by zero error, make sure that you are running on this code:

1. Check that the compiled class file is newer the source file.
2. Check that the compiled class file is first in the classpath.

Also, note **Aki**'s comment. You are creating the binary number backwards.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message you are receiving? because your `factorofTwo` can never be `0`.
`for (factorOfTwo = 1; factorOfTwo <= 128; factorOfTwo*=2)`..here it is only being incremented

Comment: yes. I agree with @AkiSuihkonen. The value of `factorofTwo` should start with `128` and be then decremented. 128-->64-->32-->and so on.